# Forward current page HTML back to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

For one of my projects I got a strange requirement, I want my current page html send back to server where i can catch that and save to a text file.Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible. I assume you are using web form.

You can use javascript to get the html and store in a hidden field:

```
document.getElementById('<%= hidHTML.ClientID %>').value = encodeURI(document.body.innerHTML);
```

On server, you can decode using HttpUtility and save to database

Comment: Sorry to say that I am not using web-form.I am transforming xml to html using xslt in my page.can you give me any idea for this?

Comment: the idea is the same if you are using MVC. Try to use a hidden field to store your xml

Answer (score 1):

you can get the html of full page by using `document.body.innerHTML`

here is the demo for this : http://jsfiddle.net/qCTvE/4/

Comment: can you suggest a way for me to send this html back to server? So that i can save it there

Comment: @AKS - you can get body like this and than use AJAX doe to sent it back to server ...

Comment: I am unable to use ajax here.as an error comes url is too long(i am passing entire html of page to url)